# Adding/Removing row dynamically in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this particular snippet..

```
newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
//alert(newcell.childNodes);
switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
case "text":
    newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
    break;
case "checkbox":
    newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
    break;
case "select-one":
    newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
    break;
case "number":
    newcell.childNodes[0].value = '';
    break;
}
```

the switch above makes the newly added rows to reset the value from the copied row.

the text and number resets.

but the drop-down and checkboxes do not

what commands does these two need to reset their values?
for the dropdown, the first option and for the checkboxes is no box is checked

**EDIT: this is the whole code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell=row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML=table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                    break;
                case "checkbox":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                    break;
                case "select-one":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                    break;
                case "number":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].value = '';
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[colCount-1].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                if(rowCount <= 2) {
                    alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                    break;
                }
                table.deleteRow(i);
                rowCount--;
                i--;
            } 
        }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
</script>
<body>
<label><input type="checkbox" id='checkboxId'>N/A</label>   
<br>
<div id="div-table-id">
    <table id='table-id' border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Subject</th>
            <th>Section Code</th>
            <th>Room</th>
            <th>Days</th>
            <th>Start Time</th>
            <th>End Time</th>
            <th>Hours Per Week</th>
            <th>No of Students (A)</th>
            <th>Course Credit w/o multiplier(B)</th>
            <th>Student Credit Units (AxB)</th>
            <th>Teaching Load Credits with Multiplier</th>
            <th>Delete?</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select name="subject" >
                    <option value="cmsc2">CMSC2</option>
                    <option value="cmsc11" selected="selected">CMSC11</option>
                    <option value="cmsc121">CMSC121</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><input type="text" id="password" value="sample"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="password2" value="sample"/></td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="m" checked>M
                <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="t">T
                <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="m">W
                <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="th">Th
                <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="f">F
                <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="s">S
            </td>
            <td><input type="time" name="start_time"></td>
            <td><input type="time" name="end_time"></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="hpw"></td>   
            <td><input type="number" name="nos"></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="ccm"></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="scu"></td>
            <td><input type="number" name="tlcm"></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="chk"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onclick="addRow('table-id')" />
    <input type="button" value="Delete Row" onclick="deleteRow('table-id')"/>       
    <input type="button" value="Save"/>

</div>

<script>
    document.getElementById('checkboxId').onchange = function () {
        var elems = document.getElementById('div-table-id').querySelectorAll('input,select,textarea');
        if (document.getElementById('checkboxId').checked) {
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                elems[i].disabled = true;
            }
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                elems[i].disabled = false;
            }    
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('password2').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('password').onblur = function(){
        if(document.getElementById('password').value != '')
            document.getElementById('password2').disabled = false;
        else{
            document.getElementById('password2').value = '';
            document.getElementById('password2').disabled = true;
        }
        document.getElementById("password2").select();
    }
    document.getElementById('password2').onblur = function (){
        if(document.getElementById('password').value == '')
            return;
        check();
    }

    function check() {
        if (document.getElementById('password2').value != document.getElementById('password').value) {
            alert('The two passwords must match.');
            document.getElementById("password").select();
            document.getElementById('password2').value = '';
        }
        else 
            alert('The two passwords matched.');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: put in `jsfiddle`, http://jsfiddle.net/ for ease of solving your question

Comment: Try `newcell.childNodes[0].removeAttribute('checked');` for the checkbox. Code for `select` looks fine to me, not sure why it wouldn't work. Can you post example HTML?

Comment: @christian314159
edited the question and posted the whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured out what your problem is. When you assign your new table cell's content to be the first row's content like so

```
newcell.innerHTML=table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;
```

you copy along a bit of white space around your input/select elements sometimes which become text nodes. Thus your DOM will actually look like this in case of your SELECT element in the first TD:

- [0] #Text node
- [1] SELECT
- [2] #Text node

This means when you grab the first child `newcell.childNodes[0]` you grab the Text node and the SELECT or CHECKBOX stays untouched.
I rewrote your code including a function that will reset all children of a new cell, as this also covers cases where someone checked more checkboxes in the first row which you use to append a new row.

```
function addRow(tableID) {

        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for( var i=0; i < colCount; i++ ){

            var newcell=row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML=table.rows[1].cells[i].innerHTML;

            resetChildren( newcell );
        }
    }

function resetChildren( parentEl ){
    var len = parentEl.childNodes.length,
        i = 0,
        el;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++){

        el = parentEl.childNodes[i];

        console.log( i, el.type, el );

        switch( el.type ){
            case "text":
                el.value = "";
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                el.removeAttribute('checked');
                break;
            case "select-one":
                el.selectedIndex = 0;
                break;
            case "number":
                el.value = '';
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice answer. Thanks to this but I just saw your answer now. I've made a solution that I add an additional row that is blank and I just copy it to add row.not the first row but the last blank row. sorry for the inconvenience but when I tried your work, it works like a charm. thanks by the way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668870/reset-all-inputs-from-field-when-checkbox-is-checked-with-javascript/23669227#23669227
i've got a followup problem, hope you can solve it. thanks